# Configuring a dynamic cascading parameter

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

In my report I can limit my selection with an optional parameter. How can I set up a second parameter with a drop-down list that changes its values based on what you picked for the first parameter?

For example, if I select "Asia" in the first parameter, the drop-down list would show Japan, Taiwan, Korea and so on. And Germany, France and UK would appear in the second parameter drop-down list if I select "Europe" in the first parameter.

Comment: How do you launch your report? From another program? A program that you wrote?

Comment: No, it is an interface from a web-base software of LIMS (Laboratory Information Management System). So that I could design a report and run it to get some conclusion or a overview in LIMS.

Comment: What I want to do with this report is that I could select a period (the first parameter) to limit the result of the second parameter which includes the experimental plans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a *[dynamic cascading parameter](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=682112&seqNum=6)* for this.

The gist is that you'll make a parameter, set to *Dynamic*, that will populate based on the selection in your prior parameter. This will query the database twice, but if you're prepared for that, select database fields in the parameters: `Country`, then `City` - or whatever you called them.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It works well!!!  May I ask another question....If I want the first parameter to be static and second one is dynamic, is it possible? For example, the first parameter is a date which could set like after(or before) 2017-07-01 and the second parameter would show the results followed by the first parameter rule.

Comment: @Mark I'll admit I haven't tried that before, but you could give it a shot and see what happens.